# Rails: Sending scheduled emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the ["resque" gem](https://github.com/resque/resque) along with "[resque-scheduler](https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler/)". I have to send out 10,000+ emails a week (about 1,500 a day). My email table has a boolean called "sent" (true/false).

Would it be best if I use the "enqueue_at" method & just have a bunch of queued emails (not sure if they literally get queued in resque.. maybe someone can clarify this) Or would it be better if I do a cron type task and just run down all the emails where the "sent" boolean is "false" & update it to "true" after the emails are sent?

**Which would be the best solution & why?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using a cron**

- Automatically pull out unsent emails and mark them as "sent"
- Only check emails every X time (the time you set in your cron file)

**Using enqueue_at**

- You have to explicitely tell the job to fire in X time (`Resque.enqueue_at(5.days.from_now, SomeJob)`)

I would do a cron task using resque-scheduler and select only unsent emails in my worker to process them and finally mark them as sent.

Comment: Thanks David & Pierre. I'm still new to rails & was just kinda' over thinking this.